How to get the correct URL from S3Client for IBM COS S3 storage details?
The sample bucket details of IBM COS S3 are as below
Bucket Name: icos-abc-prod-01-abc-02
Endpoint:  https://icos.abc.us-region.internal.das

We are using below code to create S3Client object.
credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(VAL_ACCESS_KEY_ID, VAL_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
                if (1==1) {
                    log.info("Trying to get file system of S3 Compatible.");
                    S3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                                    VAL_END_POINT_REGION, "us-east-1"))
                            .build();
                    bucketName = VAL_BUCKET_NAME;
                }

With this code is place, when we are performing
if (S3Client.doesObjectExist(bucketName, tempTgtFileName))
{
}

It checks the host name as bucketname.endpoint(without https) i.e., icos-abc-prod-01-abc-02.icos.abc.us-region.internal.das
which is incorrect.
The expected host name should be icos.abc.us-region.internal.das.
What is wrong in the S3Client object?

you need to switch to path style access so that the sdk doesn't prepend the bucket name as a hostname
Add a line to the builder chain:
.withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)

